# Como não permitir que o navegador salve a senha digitada?

Tags: html, input, password

Neste site se você fizer o login o navegador não pede pra salvar a senha e se você entrar novamente os campos estarão em branco.

Como ele faz isso?
Procurei na web, achei umas dicas mas nenhuma eficiente como este site, pelo menos no crhome.

Segue o link, usuario e senha

```
http://demo1.centos-webpanel.com:2082
User: testacc
Senha: admin123
```

Comment: **Relacionado:** [Não deixar navegador salvar a senha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/298747/3635)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se existem campos password o navegador sempre perguntará se o usuário quer salvar a senha. Isso não tem como interferir. Você até pode adicionar o atributo `autocomplete="off"` no seu form: `<form action="#" method="post" autocomplete="off">`.
Porém isso irá apenas impedir o autocomplete quando o usuário logar novamente.

Uma solução para esse problema seria mudar o `type="password"` do campo da senha para um tipo `type="text"`. O css juntamente com uma fonte pode ser usado para contornar o problema da máscara:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'password';
  font-style: normal;      
  src: url(https://jsbin-user-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/rafaelcastrocouto/password.ttf);
}
#password {
  font-family: 'password';
  width: 100px; height: 16px;  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Your password">
```

Comment: É uma boa solução, mas aí dependo do link de terceira pra pegar a fonte né?

Comment: Consegui resolver com as dicas do stack

<input name="senhapessoal" type="password" id="senhapessoal" required autocomplete="off" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');this.select();" onBlur="this.setAttribute('readonly', true);" />

Comment: Tem o porém da fonte. Mas sua solução também resolve ;).  Posso te garantir  que funcionará em qualquer browser.

Comment: Qual é garantido, da fonte ou o meu? rs

Comment: hum... será que consigo baixar a fonte na minha maquina e te-la como base pra não depender de link terceiro?

Comment: https://jsbin-user-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/rafaelcastrocouto/password.ttf é só entrar aqui e salvar

Comment: blz, grato marcada como aceita

Answer (score 0):

No caso do seu exemplo, a autenticação é feita por ajax e não executa o submit do formulário, impedindo o navegador de armazenar a senha.

Para outros casos, você pode usar o `autocomplete='off'` nos inputs.

```
<input type='text' name='username' autocomplete='off'>
```

---

## Chrome forçando a barra

### Alternativa 1

Para converter o caso do Chrome forçar o save da senha, pode fazer algo assim, passando um string qualquer ao invés do off no autocomplete.

```
<input type="text" name="field" autocomplete="nope">
```

### Alternativa 2

Outra alternativa é inclui um password invisível acima do password real, o Google Chrome aplica essa regra apenas para o primeiro input, logo o seu ficará a salvo disso.

```
<input style="opacity: 0;position: absolute;">
<input type="password" style="opacity: 0;position: absolute;">
```

Comment: Acontece o seguinte, nos meus testes em outra pagina preenchi o campos senha e enviei, agora o chrome insiste em deixar todos os campos de outras páginas tipo password preenchidos com a ultima senha usada, ja tentei de tudo aqui pra limpar isso e não consigo, o chrome faz isso depois da página carregada, preciso avisar o chrome que aquele campo específico não deve ser preenchido, mas está difícil. autocomplete='off' não funciona

Comment: Isso é magia negra do Chrome, veja aqui uma solução: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22694173/6394559